# Is it possible to enable the "Show layout bounds" developer option programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

For example, I can manipulate ADB debugging using:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, 1);
```

Is it possible to enable the "Show layout bounds" option in a similar manner? I haven't been able to find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, AFAIK it is not available. One thing I have done, however, is tint all my views to see where they are bound and where they overlap, etc. You can use this code, which uses my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library to select all views to iterate over:

```
public static void debugLayout(View layout)
{
    $.with(layout).selectAll().each(new Function() {
        @Override
        public void invoke($ d, Object... args) {
            View v = d.view(0);
            Drawable drawable = v.getBackground();
            if (drawable != null)
                drawable.setColorFilter(0xAAFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            else
                drawable = new ColorDrawable(0xAAFF0000);
            try {
                //API 16+
                v.setBackground(drawable);
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be something you can do to simulate what the Settings code actually does:
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/DevelopmentSettings.java#L942

```
private void writeDebugLayoutOptions() {
    SystemProperties.set(View.DEBUG_LAYOUT_PROPERTY,
        mDebugLayout.isChecked() ? "true" : "false");
    pokeSystemProperties();
}
```

Comment: The references does not exist anymore which turns this example not that useful

Comment: Looks like it moved to somewhere around https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/development/ShowLayoutBoundsPreferenceController.java